# How I can get the filtered grid results in the server side controller code

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, razor, telerik, asp.net-mvc-4

My Code:

```
    [GridAction]
    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public ActionResult SearchUserByFilter(string filterString, bool loadData)
    {
            // code..
            return View(new GridModel { Data = advanceSearchCaching });
    }
```

**return View(new GridModel { Data = advanceSearchCaching });** code contains the result set of the initial search conditions like in textboxes(first name, last name..). But it does not have the filtered result from the grid(that is filtering from the grid by using filter option). How to get the filtered grid results in the server side controller code. Thanks.

Comment: Are you using Telerik's grid?

Comment: Yes, I am using Telerik MVC Grid. Thanks.

Comment: I use Kendo's grid + ajax for filtering and ordering. Have you ever tried it? http://demos.kendoui.com/web/grid/column-menu.html